# iphone sdk CGAffineTransform getting the angle of rotation of an object

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

how do i calculate the angle of rotation for any given object (ie a uiimageview)?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Technically you can't, because the transform can include a *skew* operation which turns the image into a parallelogram and the rotation angle isn't defined anymore.

Anyway, since the rotation matrix generates

```
 cos(x)  sin(x)   0
-sin(x)  cos(x)   0
   0        0     1
```

You can recover the angle with

```
return atan2(transform.b, transform.a);
```

Comment: what is transform.b and transform.a? are b and a properties of an transform? have never seen those.

Comment: @openfrog: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000946-CH2g-BBCJFFAE

Answer (score 36):

You can easily get the angle of the rotation like this:

```
CGFloat angle = [(NSNumber *)[view valueForKeyPath:@"layer.transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];
```

---

For example:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.02);
CGFloat angle = [(NSNumber *)[view valueForKeyPath:@"layer.transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];
NSLog(@"%f", angle); // 0.020000
```

---

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Key-ValueCodingExtensions/Key-ValueCodingExtensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH12-SW1):

> Core Animation extends the key-value coding protocol to allow getting and setting of the common values of a layer's CATransform3D matrix through key paths. Table 4 describes the key paths for which a layer’s transform and sublayerTransform properties are key-value coding and observing compliant

Comment: Where is the documentation for this? While this is nice, I'm not sure it would pass apple's inspection.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - Here it is: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006082-SW17

Comment: Great answer, saved me from a huge problem. +1

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use acos and asin functions. You will get exactly the same result:

```
 NSLog (@"%f %f %f", acos (MyView.transform.a), asin (MyView.transform.b), atan2(MyView.transform.b, MyView.transform.a) );
```

Comment: The identity you suggest is only true if there is no scaling. If there is scaling also, you have to use the atan() function.

Comment: very helpful, shot and easy answer +1

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    CGPoint newLocationPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.superview];
    int x = self.center.x;
    int y = self.center.y;    
    float dx = newLocationPoint.x - x;
    float dy = newLocationPoint.y - y;    
    double angle = atan2(-dx,dy);  
    self.layer.position = self.center;
    self.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0, 0, 1); 
    NSLog(@"touchesMoved %f %f %d,%d   %f,%f  angle:%f",newLocationPoint.x,newLocationPoint.y,x,y,dx,dy,angle);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old question but, if anyone like me faces with this problem using CALayers and CATransform3D, you can get angle with:

```
extension CATransform3D {

    var xAxisAngle: CGFloat { get { return atan2(self.m23, self.m33) } }
    var yAxisAngle: CGFloat { get { return atan2(self.m31, self.m11) } }
    var zAxisAngle: CGFloat { get { return atan2(self.m12, self.m11) } }

}
```