# iPhoneSDK calculate Rotation angle from CATransform3D

Tags: iphone, core-animation, catransform3d

How do I calculate the Rotation in Radians around Z-axis by giving a CATransform3D struct as the input?

basically what I need is the other way round of `CATransform3DMakeRotation`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It depends on what axis you are doing the rotation on.

Rotation about the z-axis is represented as:

```
a  = angle in radians
x' = x*cos.a - y*sin.a
y' = x*sin.a + y*cos.a
z' = z

( cos.a  sin.a  0  0)
(-sin.a  cos.a  0  0)
( 0        0    1  0)
( 0        0    0  1)
```

so angle should be **a = atan2(transform.m12, transform.m11);**

Rotation about x-axis:

```
a  = angle in radians
y' = y*cos.a - z*sin.a
z' = y*sin.a + z*cos.a
x' = x

(1    0      0    0)
(0  cos.a  sin.a  0)
(0 -sin.a  cos.a  0)
(0    0     0     1)
```

Rotation about y-axis:

```
a  = angle in radians
z' = z*cos.a - x*sin.a
x' = z*sin.a + x*cos.a
y' = y

(cos.a  0  -sin.a   0)
(0      1    0      0)
(sin.a  0  cos.a    0)
(0      0    0      1)
```

Comment: Be sure to use atan2 and not atan as the later will not give an angle in the correct quadrant.

Comment: Thank you Nader, before your answer, I had resorted back to using CALayer's affineTransform property convert the Transform3D into an AffineTransform and then get the angle out of it from this calculation:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051811/iphone-sdk-cgaffinetransform-getting-the-angle-of-rotation-of-an-object
Now I know, how to calculate directly from Transform3D. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I learned about this back in first year uni and can remember asking my friend "why the he'll do we need to know this"

Comment: You can calculate the angle from an affine transform too using atan2(transform.b, transform.a), the maths still holds true for a z-axis rotation

Answer (score 17):

If the transform is attached to a layer, then you can get the value of the rotation like follows:

```
CGFloat angle = [(NSNumber *)[layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];
```

---

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Key-ValueCodingExtensions/Key-ValueCodingExtensions.html):

> Core Animation extends the key-value coding protocol to allow getting and setting of the common values of a layer's CATransform3D matrix through key paths. Table 4 describes the key paths for which a layer’s transform and sublayerTransform properties are key-value coding and observing compliant