# iOS SDK CGAffineTransform Angle Question

Tags: ios, angle, cgaffinetransform, radians

I need to get angle in radians.  I have:

CGFloat angle = asin(myImage.transform.b);

This seems to be not working.  I need to extract the angle of 'myImage' at any moment in time.  How would I extract this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone sdk CGAffineTransform getting the angle of rotation of an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051811/iphone-sdk-cgaffinetransform-getting-the-angle-of-rotation-of-an-object)

Answer (score 1):

CGFloat angle = atan2(card.transform.b, card.transform.a);

That does it.