# Get the current angle/rotation/radian for a UIView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, rotation

How do you get the current angle/rotation/radian a UIView has?

Comment: I know it should be like myView.transformation something.. but hooow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone sdk CGAffineTransform getting the angle of rotation of an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051811/iphone-sdk-cgaffinetransform-getting-the-angle-of-rotation-of-an-object)

Comment: @Abizern not really, He's asking for how to do it with CGAffineTransform. Which you can't.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You can do it this way...

```
CGFloat radians = atan2f(yourView.transform.b, yourView.transform.a); 
CGFloat degrees = radians * (180 / M_PI);
```

Comment: I would vote you up for 10! I just happened to come across this post and had to laugh as I totally forgot about inverse trigonometry! Just as I was starting to feel that my school education all those years ago was a waste :D

Answer (score 17):

Swift:

```
// Note the type reference as Swift is now string Strict

let radians:Double = atan2( Double(yourView.transform.b), Double(yourView.transform.a))
let degrees:CGFloat = radians * (CGFloat(180) / CGFloat(M_PI) )
```

Answer (score 8):

A lot of the other answers reference `atan2f`, but given that we're operating on `CGFloat`s, we can just use `atan2` and skip the unnecessary intermediate cast:

#### Swift 4:

```
let radians = atan2(yourView.transform.b, yourView.transform.a)
let degrees = radians * 180 / .pi
```

Answer (score 6):

For Swift 3, you could use the following code:

```
let radians:Float = atan2f(Float(view.transform.b), Float(view.transform.a))
let degrees:Float = radians * Float(180 / M_PI)
```

Answer (score 6):

//For Swift 3: M_PI is depreciated now Use Double.pi

```
let radians = atan2f(Float(yourView.transform.b), Float(yourView.transform.a));
let degrees = radians * Float(180 / Double.pi)
```

//For Swift 4:

```
let radians = atan2(yourView.transform.b, yourView.transform.a)
let degrees = radians * 180 / .pi
```

Answer (score 2):

In swift 2 and Xcode 7 :

```
let RdnVal = CGFloat(atan2f(Float(NamVyu.transform.b), Float(NamVyu.transform.a)))
let DgrVal = RdnVal * CGFloat(180 / M_PI)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using extensions:

```
extension UIView {
    
    var rotation: Float {
        let radians:Float = atan2f(Float(transform.b), Float(transform.a))
        return radians * Float(180 / M_PI)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let view = UIView()
print(view.rotation)
```