# How to get perfect X , Y position of rotating UIView in iOS

Tags: ios, rotation, position, cabasicanimation

I am using CABasicanimation for rotate an UIView. I am using this code:

```
    CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    NSNumber *currentAngle = [CircleView.layer.presentationLayer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    rotationAnimation.fromValue = currentAngle;
    rotationAnimation.toValue = @(50*M_PI);
    rotationAnimation.duration = 50.0f;             // this might be too fast
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;     // HUGE_VALF is defined in math.h so import it
    [CircleView.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimationleft"];
```

in this I want perfect X,Y position while "UIView" is rotating. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more what you mean by perfect x and y position and which way your view has to rotate? Do you want it to rotate in the Z axis (so in 3D space?).

Comment: Actually i am rotating my UIView in both side and on click event and when this UIView is rotating i want a perfect position of that UIView that at which position it is actually.

Comment: i want a position in manner of (X,Y)

Comment: No It is not like 3d not in z. i am simply rotating UIVew on same position of UIView.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand you correctly, you just want to get the X and Y coordinates of your view during rotation?

You can do this by logging the frame of the presentationLayer, like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender {

    CGRect position = [[CircleView.layer presentationLayer] frame];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(position));
}
```

Comment: Hello Friend Thanx For Your Answer But This not give me a perfect position

Comment: I tried your code and my answer, you are right, the presentationlayer doesn't give the correct coordinates in the superviews coordinate space. At this moment, I do not understand why. I'll come back to it if I find out.

Comment: Ok Thanx Please Tell me if you are having any idea about it.