# get image view exact frame after transformed/rotation apply in landscape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, transform, image-rotation

I am working on an app where I have just assign the transformation to image view when device rotated in landscape mode. Now I want exact frame of that image view after transformation applied to it. I have tried with this example: [Find Frame Coordinates After UIView Transform is Applied (CGAffineTransform)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523487/find-frame-coordinates-after-uiview-transform-is-applied-cgaffinetransform?lq=1) but not succeeded. Code I have used:

```
UIView *Newview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_FullImageView.frame];
_FullImageView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);

_FullImageView.frame = CGRectMake(Newview.frame.origin.x, Newview.frame.origin.y,Newview.frame.size.width,Newview.frame.size.height);

_FullImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

If anybody have any suggestion then please let me know. It would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following code. Hope you need the same.

```
UIView*Newview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_FullImageView.frame];
```

_FullImageView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);

```
CGRect rect = _FullImageView.frame;
```

Check rect frame , it gives you the frame after transform.

Comment: This code always return (CGRect) rect = (origin = (x = -67.5, y = 67.5), size = (width = 455, height = 320))   but when I transform the image view then image display according to ratio and fit in image view accordingly I need that image view image frame after rotation. Thanks.