# getting view current rotation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, cgaffinetransform

is there a way to extract rotation information (only , without scale/translation) info from a CGAffineTransform ?

I would like to apply the rotation to another object, but without setting translation/scale.

Comment: Maybe answered here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051811/iphone-sdk-cgaffinetransform-getting-the-angle-of-rotation-of-an-object

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can extract the values used in a function and reference them directly in some other function.

What you can do is define a `CGFloat angle` struct outside any of the functions and just reuse it whenever you need the same value for a rotation transform.

Comment: the rotation is calculated  via multi touch event, I dont know how to maintain angle from that code :   CGAffineTransform incrementalTransform = [self incrementalTransformWithTouches:[event touchesForView:self]];
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(originalTransform, incrementalTransform);