# How can I get the view's current rotation after use core animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

I use core animation to rotate a view, after animation complete I want to kown the view's current rotation, but it trouble me.

```
CABasicAnimation *angleAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
angleAnimation.toValue = @(45 * M_PI / 180);
angleAnimation.duration = 3;
angleAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
angleAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
angleAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    CGFloat rotationAngle = [[[testView.layer presentationLayer] valueForKey:@"transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"rotationAngle = %f", rotationAngle);
}];
[testView.layer addAnimation:angleAnimation forKey:nil];
[CATransaction commit];
```

In above code,I use **[[[testView.layer presentationLayer] valueForKey:@"transform.rotation.z"] floatValue]** method to get the layer's current rotation , this method is seached on stackoverflow,but just not work for me.Anyone knows why?

Can someone help me?

Sorry for my mistake.**[[[testView.layer presentationLayer] valueForKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"] floatValue]** just work.

Comment: Have you tried valueForKeyPath: ?

Comment: May help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051811/iphone-sdk-cgaffinetransform-getting-the-angle-of-rotation-of-an-object

Comment: @jrturton Yes!It work for me.Its my fault to use **valueFoKey** but not **valueForKeyPath** Thx!   KudoCC It seems work for view's transform but not the view layer's transform.Thank you all the same!

Comment: I've added that as an answer, then, rather than leave it in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`valueForKey:` expects a single key. You need to use `valueForKeyPath:`, since you are asking for the value of a key *path* (several keys separated by periods) instead.