# Xcode 5.1 How do I use the SpriteKit in one view in a project that doesn't use the Sprite game template?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I just need this view to be a sticker page where the user can move and place stickers.

I have a view connected to the `StickerViewController`, and I simply copy and pasted this code into the class for it. Everything builds ok, but crashes before it even makes it to the `StickerViewController`.

I use a simple button for testing, so I know that the view controller is not loading properly and I placed breakpoints. I did not start this project using the SpriteKit template. I have only been programming iOS mobile apps for 3 weeks, so I still new to this.

In the header, I import `UIKit` and `SpriteKit`.Then:

```
@interface StickersViewController : SKScene @end
```

In the m file, instead of having `initWithNibName` I have `initWithSize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `UIKit Dynamics`. Detailed tutorial available here [UIKIt Dynamics](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50197/uikit-dynamics-tutorial)

Please refer also to this answer [Implement UIKitDynamics for dragging view off screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325057/implement-uikitdynamics-for-dragging-view-off-screen)

Answer (score 0):

This project is a `UIKit` app eventually with 5 different `SpriteKit` scenes inside. https://github.com/eppz/blog.SpriteKit_drag May take a look on it.

Basically I made an `SKView` subclass - https://github.com/eppz/blog.SpriteKit_drag/blob/master/SpriteKit_drag/EPPZSpriteKitView.h - then set it as the root `UIViewController.view` class in IB.