# Set imageview orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

Im using `UIImageview` that moves according to a timer selector. Its center moves a certain x and y axis ammounts. Now I want this image to rotate in time, that means, I need to add a float constant called 'w' which will be the angle that my image will rotate every time the selector runs. 
I need to know if there is any possible way to access the `UIImageView` current orientation and modify it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to rotate your UIImageView you can use this

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(imageView.transform, M_PI / 2.0f);
imageView.transform = transform;
```

use this in your timer method with respect to your current rotation degree.

Answer (score 0):

First of all;

```
#define degreesToRadians( degrees ) ( ( degrees ) / 180.0 * M_PI )
```

this will convert from degrees to radians for transform

this is a method that you should call to turn imageview

```
-(void)rotateImage
{
    yourImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(atan2(yourImageView.transform.b, yourImageView.transform.a)+degreesToRadians(delta));
    k++;
}
```

delta is the amount of rotation. as an angle.

atan2(b,a) gets the current rotation of your imageview.
for more detailed answer [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051811/iphone-sdk-cgaffinetransform-getting-the-angle-of-rotation-of-an-object)