# readout the radius of a rotated UIImage

Tags: ios, rotation, uiimage

In my UIView the User can place different UIImages.
The User can move and rotate these images.

The Images, type, position are saved in a array for later restore.

I also want to save the ration degree.

Is it possible to read out the degree of the rotated images ?
Or must I save the degree at the moment when the images are rotated ?

thanks

Comment: this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051811/iphone-sdk-cgaffinetransform-getting-the-angle-of-rotation-of-an-object

Comment: Could you not provide an extension or subclass the uiimage to be some custom type, say UserImage and in there have a ration property that you increment the angle on each rotation, that way you can be sure if you reset the angle to 0 the image will return to its starting origin?  If you want to store multiple rotations for undo operations. why not add a stack that remembers the last 10 configurations of that object?

Answer (score 1):

Just remember the rotation at the moment when it is rotated - why make it more complicated than that?

Comment: I think its more complicated to save every ration.
Because the User can Rotate the Image himself.
He can rotate the Image by using a button.
And when the Image is moved It rotates some times automatically.

For every Rotation I have a separate code. 
So when I want to save it at the moment by the rotation I must save the ration in every code part of every rotation.

So my Idee is when the User is finished, is leaving or the Programm is canceled, something else THEN I saved one times every Image Position, size, rotation.

Comment: But when you rotate the image you do know the rotation - you don't have to SAVE it then, but you have the value somewhere in your class. Just save it to persistent storage when the action is finished, of course.

Comment: But is it possible or not to read out the rotation at a later point ?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051811/iphone-sdk-cgaffinetransform-getting-the-angle-of-rotation-of-an-object

Answer (score 0):

@TheEye: not realy.
I think in the link there is the solution. but I'm to stupid to adapt it to my app....

Here is the code where the rotation is done and saved but i works not very fine.

```
- (IBAction)rotateImage:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    snap = 0;
    NSMutableDictionary *itemDSNew = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *itemDSOld = (NSDictionary *)[messestandItems objectAtIndex:aktivItemID];

    if (messestandItems.count > 2) {
        CGFloat netRotation = [[itemDSOld objectForKey:@"rotation"] floatValue];
        CGFloat rotation = [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)sender rotation];
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation+netRotation);
        aktivImageView.transform = transform;

        if (sender.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
            netRotation += rotation;
            }
        [itemDSNew addEntriesFromDictionary:itemDSOld];
        [itemDSNew setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", aktivImageView.center.x] forKey:@"posX"];
        [itemDSNew setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", aktivImageView.center.y] forKey:@"posY"];
        [itemDSNew setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", rotation + netRotation] forKey:@"rotation"];
        [itemDSNew setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"] forKey:@"snap"];
        [messestandItems replaceObjectAtIndex:aktivItemID withObject:itemDSNew];
        [messestandItems writeToFile:[self saveFilePath] atomically:YES];
        }
}
```

this is my code to rotate 45°:

```
float rad = M_PI * (float)45 / 180.0;
aktivImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(aktivImageView.transform, rad);
```

but what is the code when i later in the app want to know the transform (rad)

something like:

```
rad = aktivImageView.transform;
float degree = rad * 180 / M_PI;
```

and then i have the degree which the User had rotated the Image ?